# Django UpdatingProfile form

Tags: python, django

I am building an application that allows users to view and edit their own personal profile. Users are able to view their profile and the profile is editable from the admin side. However when a user tries to edit their own info, they are getting a `NameError` telling them that `args` is not defined. Below is how I have tried to implement the editing functionality:

**forms**

```
class UpdateProfile(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(required=False)
    email = forms.EmailField(required=False)
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=False)
    age = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    height = forms.IntegerField(required=False)
    weight = forms.IntegerField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
#These are the fields that i want to be made editable. 
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'age', 'height', 'weight')


    def clean_email(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')

        if email and User.objects.filter(email=email).exclude(username=username).count():
            raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use. Please supply a different email address.')
        return email

    def save(self, commit=True):
        super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

#Here i am trying to add the new data to the users profile
        if commit:
            user_profile.user.save()

        return user_profile
```

**Views**

```
def update_profile(request):
    args = {}

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UpdateProfile(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('account/profile.html'))

    else:
        form = UpdateProfile()
        args['form'] = form
        return render(request, 'account/edit_profile.html', args)
```

Comment: please add the error with more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In form's `save` method you are using `args` and `kwargs` variables which were not declared. Replace them with `commit`:

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    super(UpdateProfile, self).__init__(commit)
```